# Rails 2.3.11 ActionMailer doesn't render html when email has attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, actionmailer

I am using Rails 2.3.11. I created a UserMailer with following methods:

```
     def rsvp_created(user, rsvp, pdf_file)
        setup_email(user)
        content_type "multipart/mixed"
        @subject << "Your RSVP for #{rsvp.ticket.holiday.title}"
        @body[:rsvp] = rsvp

        attachment :content_type => 'application/pdf', 
                   :body => File.read(pdf_file), 
                   :filename => "#{rsvp.confirmation_number}.pdf"
      end

      def rsvp_cancelled(user, rsvp)
        setup_email(user)
        content_type "text/html"
        @subject << "Cancelled RSVP for #{rsvp.ticket.holiday.title}"
        @body[:rsvp] = rsvp
        @body[:holiday_url] = APP_CONFIG['site_url'] + holiday_path(rsvp.ticket.holiday)
      end

protected
  def setup_email(user)
    @recipients = "#{user.email}"
    @from = APP_CONFIG['admin_email']
    @subject = "[#{APP_CONFIG['site_name']}] "
    @sent_on = Time.now
    @body[:user] = user
  end
```

The rsvp_cancelled works fine and sends email properly.  But the rsvp_created email, which has an attachment, doesn't work properly. It sends the email with the attached file but doesn't render any text. Any one faced this issue before or know how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rails 2.x, for some reason or the other you need to define all the parts for the HTML to appear.

```
def rsvp_created(user, rsvp, pdf_file)
  setup_email(user)
  content_type "multipart/mixed"
  @subject << "Your RSVP for #{rsvp.ticket.holiday.title}"

  part :content_type => 'multipart/alternative' do |copy|
    copy.part :content_type => 'text/html' do |html|
      html.body = render( :file => "rsvp_created.text.html.erb", 
                          :body => { :rsvp => rsvp } )
    end
  end

  attachment :content_type => 'application/pdf', 
             :body => File.read(pdf_file), 
             :filename => "#{rsvp.confirmation_number}.pdf"

end
```

Thankfully it appears this is not the case in Rails 3.x.

Comment: I love Rails 3. But I am working on a project that was developed in 2.3.11. So i have to unlearn Rails 3 things. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same sort of thing, but following Douglas' answer above, kept getting corrupted pdf attachments.  I was finally able to resolve the issue by reading the pdf file in binary mode:

```
attachment :content_type => 'application/pdf', 
           :body => File.open(pdf_file, 'rb') {|f| f.read} 
           :filename => "#{rsvp.confirmation_number}.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get mine working with Douglas' answer but was also able to get it working in one line.  I was using a template but this also works by substituting "rsvp" for the render_message method.

```
part :content_type => "text/html", 
     :body => render_message("template_name", { :symbol => value } )
```